# What's the difference between diuretic veggies and alcohol that make the latter bad?

Tags: nutrition

So I'm reading this article to [Treat Fluid Retention](http://www.wikihow.com/Treat-Fluid-Retention) and it suggests

1. Eat foods with diuretic properties.

But also

1. Avoid drinks that will dehydrate the body such as tea, coffee and alcohol.

As I understand, tea, coffee and alcohol are plenty diuretic. So what makes those veggies's diuretic nature better than alcohol's?

I know alcohol is more harmful than veggies, but I mainly wanted to know **how do diuretic veggies help you** when infact the diuretic alcohol actually makes you dehyderated? How's veggies' **diuretic nature** more helpful than the alcohol's (disregarding other side-effects of it)?

Comment: This question is primarily concerned with the *mechanism* behind a supposed effect of certain vegetables, and does not ask for any treatment suggestions. Voting to reopen.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly I would suggest if you have concerns about suffering from symptoms fluid overload you should consult your doctor. Self diagnosis and self treatment is not a good option.

In terms of alcohol being used as a diuretic, you have to bear in mind that there are many deleterious effects of excess alcohol. By consuming alcohol as a diuretic you would most likely cause more health problems than you solve.

Comment: I was just researching remedies for Puffy face, nothing too serious. I know alcohol is more harmful than veggies, but I mainly wanted to know **how do diuretic veggies help you** when infact the diuretic alcohol actually makes you dehyderated? How's veggies' **diuretic nature** more helpful than the alcohol's (disregarding other side-effects of it)?